# How to disabled cloud-zoom click from product page?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, frontend

I am working on eCommerce website. link: http://www.ultimatespares.com/motorcycleparts/crash-pads-screens/crash-pads-r12-for-ducati-monster-696-2014.html

I want to disabled click from magnifying glass `.cloud-zoom-lens`. On click new window open.

I tried to add

1. css for that class `pointer-events: none;`
2. and tried in js.

but use....I think plugin is working perfectly beacuse http://www.ultimatespares.com/motorcycleparts/crash-pads-screens.html
(click on quick view and check)

So what should i do?

Comment: if you ever faced the problem, image getting divided when you hover the Product Image  : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/194453/57334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed minimize version of cloud zoom file and sort out.

Answer (score 1):

On your host there is library

> http://www.ultimatespares.com/js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js

**It's not very clear idea** but to achieve your target you need make some changes there (for example with rewrite).

If you ctrl+F word 'click' in this file you find following:

```
            $(this).bind('click', $(this), function (event) {
                var data = event.data.data('relOpts');
                // Destroy the previous zoom
                $('#' + data.useZoom).data('zoom').destroy();
                // Change the biglink to point to the new big image.
                $('#' + data.useZoom).attr('href', event.data.attr('href'));
                // Change the small image to point to the new small image.
                $('#' + data.useZoom + ' img').attr('src', event.data.data('relOpts').smallImage);
                // Init a new zoom with the new images.                
                $('#' + event.data.data('relOpts').useZoom).CloudZoom();
                return false;
            });
```

Try to remove hardly this (or part of this), to understand will it helpful or not. If yes - make an rewrite

Comment: It looks like you have two cloud-zoom libs on your host... firstly better leave only one and fix your JS errors in console

Comment: I edited this file http://www.ultimatespares.com/skin/frontend/default/theme362/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js. yes sort out that. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Have you removed [x]best answer accidentally or something is wrong?

Comment: because your answer is not right. After removal of above code, thumbnail images was opened in new tab. I uncomment above code.

Comment: If I clearly understand you, you removed code, which I wrote below from another file, right?

Comment: no you are wrong

Comment: i just removed other js file of cloud zoom