# Why Products Image Divided when i hover the images?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

When i try to hover the products images its getting divided, how can i solve this error,

[image]

Comment: some css on hover is culprit.

Comment: how can i find it, i tried lot, but i cant get anything...

Comment: F12 check which css is applying on hover of image div or <img> tag.